# How can I append lists with items from another list and leave these empty in a simulation?

Tags: python, list, append, simulate

Here is my code:

```
import random
listx = []
ready = 0
listy = []
listz = []

#function

def function(r,s,q):
    listy=[]
    if len(listx)==4 or len(listx)==8:
        listy.append((listx, t))
        print "y", listy

# here it starts:

for t in range(1,25): 

    randomnumber = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

    if randomnumber <= 0.5:
        listx.append((t))   
        print "x", listx

    if ready == 0: #condition, lets say: ready is always 0
        function(5,6,8) #this function generates listy from input of listx

    if listy != 0: #if listy is not empy anymore, fill listz with items of listy
            listz.append(listy)
            del listy
            print "z", listz
```

I have 3 lists; `listx`, `listy` and `listz`. I generate random numbers to `listx`. If `ready==0` (always) I call the function `(function(r,s,q))`. If a condition `(len==4 or 8)` is met, the items in the list are appended to listy.

At this point, I would like to add these numbers from `listy` to `listz` and leave `listy` empty again. The items that I transported from `listy` to `listz` should be removed from `listx`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: That code is weird, there are several issues in it: First, your function is not a function, since it returns no value (instead it prints a value on the screen which is fundamentally different to returning a value. Printing is useless for further processing the value). Second, the "function" uses a variable `t` which is global to the function and which is the loop-variable defined later; you should not do this. Third: You write `for items in listy`, is it because the entries in `listy` are sequences? If not, better do not name the variable in plural, this will confuse.

Comment: Your bottom two `if` statements never run

Comment: The `listy` variable in the body of `function` is not the same than the global `listy`!

Comment: Thanks for your insights. But, how can I call listy and move the items from listy to listz in this case?

Comment: Move the items from `listy` to `listz`: `listz += listy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do you want. Changes to your code are indicated with `# UPPERCASE COMMENTS`.

```
import random
listx = []
ready = 0
listy = []
listz = []

#function

def function(r,s,q):
    global listy  #### ADDED

    listy=[]
    if len(listx) in (4, 8):  # STREAMLINED
        listy.append((listx, t))
        print "y", listy

# here it starts:

for t in range(1,25):

    randomnumber = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

    if randomnumber <= 0.5:
        listx.append((t))
        print "x", listx

    if ready == 0: # condition, lets say: ready is always 0
        function(5,6,8) # this function generates listy from input of listx

    #### REWRITTEN
    if listy: # not empty?
        listz += listy[0][0]  # copy numbers from listy to listz
        del listx[:len(listy[0][0])]  # remove numbers transported from listx
        del listy  # empty listy
        print "z", listz
```

Comment: This works! Only changed listz += listy to listz += listy[0][0]